# vbscript: LDAP custom filter queries trying to search for all computers in the domain but excluding an OU or 2

Tags: vbscript, ldap

When I run:

```
Set objConnection = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set objCommand =   CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
objConnection.Provider = "ADsDSOObject"
objConnection.Open "Active Directory Provider"

strFilter = "(&(objectClass=computer))"

strAttributes = "name,distinguishedName"

strQuery = strDomainDN & ";" & strFilter & ";" & strAttributes & ";subtree"

Set objCOmmand.ActiveConnection = objConnection
objCommand.CommandText = strQuery
objCommand.Properties("Page Size") = 9999
Set objRecordSet = objCommand.Execute
objRecordSet.MoveFirst

Do Until objRecordSet.EOF
    strADObjects = strADObjects & objRecordSet.Fields("Name").Value & vbCrLf
    'Wscript.Echo "Location: " & objRecordSet.Fields("DistinguishedName").Value
    objRecordSet.MoveNext
Loop
```

my query works like a champ but when i try to filter out a specific OU, the script either throws an error or excludes nothing at all.  I've tried many different variants inside of strFilter.  Is there a way you can query an entire domain for all computers but excluding the results from a particular OU?  ...or OUs???  I've tried:

```
strFilter = "(&(objectClass=computer) (!(distinguishedName=*,OU=Computers,DC=mydomain,DC=myTLD)))"
strFilter = "(&(objectClass=computer) (!distinguishedName=*,OU=Computers,DC=mydomain,DC=myTLD))"
strFilter = "(&(objectClass=computer) (!(OU=Computers,DC=mydomain,DC=myTLD)))"
strFilter = "(&(objectClass=computer) (!OU=Computers,DC=mydomain,DC=myTLD))"
```

can anyone offer any pointers to where I might be messing this up?  TIA~!

Edit:  Also found and tried but no worky:

```
(&(!(ou:dn:=Computers))(objectClass=Computer))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, it apparently can't be done.  my first couple of attempts won't work because the distinguishedName attributed is a constructed value which means it can't be used for filtering and doesn't work with wildcards.  My answer was found on the Hey Scripting Guy! blogs:

http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2004/12/07/how-can-i-return-a-list-of-all-my-computers-except-those-in-a-specified-ou.aspx

In short, you can't do this with LDAP filtering, you have to return the entire result-set and then use a custom filter (vbscript, etc) on the results.